# Can I use this third party charger for my Asus laptop?

Tags: charger

I recently bought Asus X53E a few weeks ago and I have a third party charger which I bought a few months ago.

Can I use the third party charger on my laptop?

My Asus charger says

100-240V 1.5A INPUT
19V 3.42A OUTPUT

And then the third party does say the exact same words,

and I can plug the third party charger onto my laptop perfectly as well.

Here is the photo of the two chargers.

[Left - Third Party Charger & Right - Asus Charger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2KBt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will work perfectly.

The voltage matches and the new adapter provides sufficient current. The polarity is also the same.

Your laptop won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

**IF**

Volt's = 19v
3.42 or greater amps

Make sure **polarity** is correct! Is the positive on the **inside or outside** of adapter fitting that goes in your laptop!

100-240V 1.5A INPUT 19V 3.42A OUTPUT